# How to insert <th> tag in the table in asp.net in code behind file?

Tags: asp.net, html-table, code-behind, tablerow

I am adding table in code behind file. and i want to add  tag in that.

```
<table id="tbl" runat="server">
   <tr>
        <th>test</th>
       <td>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I dont know how to add  through code.

So can any one tell me how to add  tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HtmlTable t = tbl; //just to make it clear your table is an HtmlTable
tbl.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell("th")); //adds an emtpy cell to the first row with th tagname
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Table t = new Table();
TableHeaderRow th = new TableHeaderRow();
th.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("test"));
t.Controls.Add(th);
containerControlForTheTable.Controls.Add(t);
```

Comment: For my case, this is better than marked answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim tr As New HtmlTableRow
tr.Cells.Add(New HtmlTableCell("th"))
yourtable.Rows.Add(tr)
```